# Desplegar proyecto laravel en vps (apache)?

Tags: laravel, apache, vps

Estoy intentando subir mi proyecto de laravel a un vps, obviamente pensareis que soy imbécil preguntando como configurar apache para desplegar la app, pero me sale HTTP_ERROR 500 y ya no se me ocurre nada mas que hacer, he de decir que anteriormente he conseguido desplegar otro proyecto en este mismo hosting.

He comprado un vps de ubuntu 14.04 limpio, he instalado LAMP y he configurado apache en sites-available, para generar un archivo.conf.

Lo raro es que aun deshabilitando el sites-available/000-default, copiando el fichero y cambiando la ruta por el proyecto de laravel( recien instalado en /var/www/proyecto/public) no hay manera de que coja la configuración

He activado el modulo rewrite y he puesto el nombre del host en /etc/hosts

y sigue sin funcionar.

Alguna sugerencia por favor?¿ 
Edito:
He copiado la configuracion de mi fichero de configuracion de apache de otro servidor donde tengo desplegado un proyecto de laravel, e incluso e subido ese proyecto a este vps, y no he conseguido que funcione, he incluso reinstalado todo desde 0, pego el contenido del archivo de configuracion de apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName vps585365.ovh.net

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/api/public

    <Directory /var/www/api/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
     </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

     <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml $
    </IfModule>
```

Alguien podria resumirme que archivos de apache o laravel hay que tocar o modificar para que todo funcione correctamente, porque yo creo que me estoy olvidando algo...

Existe alguna diferencia entre debian y ubuntu? Con respecto a la configuracion de apache en el servidor. 
Edito2:
index.php de mi proyecto:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

laravel.log:

```
    [2018-09-24 15:06:52] production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException: Command "composer" is not defined. in /var/www/apigranja/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:515
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/apigranja/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(183): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('composer')
#1 /var/www/apigranja/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output$
#2 /var/www/apigranja/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Sym$
#3 /var/www/apigranja/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 {main}
```

Muchas gracias anticipado.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿No escribe nada en el registro de laravel?

Comment: verifica el .htaccess de laravel probablemente tengas que instalar algun modulo adicional a apache, incluso si esta desarollado en PHP7 tienes que volver a  hacer la instalacion de PHP

Comment: No, en el registro de laravel no escribe nada, porque parece que no llega a alcanzar al index.php, y el htaccess lo tengo exactamnete igual que mi otro proyecto. Aunque ahora me muestra el index con las carpetas de mi proyecto y html en el navegador, cuando accedo a public de mi proyecto entiendo que es cuando existe algun problema en laravel ya que me sale http error 500, al menos me lo muestra jeje

Comment: He reinstalado php, y aclaro que la paginal principal de apache si se me muestra, pero aunque no cree ningun fichero, estando dentro de html, aunque ponga mi proyecto a public inclusive, http error 500.... desesperante algo tan sencilla que de tanto por el..

Comment: a ver a mi paracer deberias instalar la ultima version de php, ademas de eso debes instalar composer que es el que gestiona las dependencias de PHP y apartir de ahi creo recordar que ya te funcionaria Laravel :) un saludo

Comment: Ya tengo todo eso instalado, y de php utilizo la version 7.0 no deberia tener problema por eso, el proyecto ya le hice composer update, osea que del proyecto no es, podria poner el htaccess pero tiene lo que dice en todos los lados el rewrite y ya, y lo raro es que no me aparece ni la pagina principal

Comment: ¿Cómo has desplegado en el servidor a nivel de carpetas? Es decir, si /var/www/htdocs es la carpeta que sirve apache, ¿dónde has puesto tú el proyecto Laravel y la carpeta public? ¿Has copiado o movido la carpeta public o has hecho un enlace simbólico? ¿el archivo index.php de public apunta a los archivos correctamente?

Comment: Hola @JaviMollá lo tengo en /var/www/proyecto/public pero habia hecho la prueba en /var/www/html/proyecto/public y aun asi no me funcionaba, que yo sepa, el unico enlace simbolico que tengo es para el phpmyadmin, no hice ninguno en el proyecto, y ya no se me ocurre nada mas que hacerle

Comment: Según el archivo de configuración del apache, la carpeta raíz de apache es /var/www/api/public y ahí debería ir todo el contenido de la carpeta public del proyecto de Laravel. Lo puedes hacer creando un enlace simbólico o copiando (o moviendo) todo ahí, incluyendo el .htaccess, y luego tendrías que actualizar el archivo index.php para actualizar las rutas a los php de arranque de Laravel

Comment: en este caso, es como esta, es la ruta correcta, estan todos los ficheros ahi, sin embargo no los coje, he probado tambien a cambiar el index.php de laravel y modificar el htaccess haciendo siempre copia, pero aaun asi no consigo que me lance el index. Pero la pregunta que me hago es, tiene que ir en html? o puede ir en cualquier ruta dentro de /var/www? obviamente he reiniciado apache nose ya ni cuantas veces

Comment: Yo te digo lo que veo en el fichero que has puesto: la carpeta raíz de apache, la que sirve cuando pones http://servidor, es /var/www/api/public y ahí debería ir el index.php

Comment: Es donde esta, y en api, estan todas las carpetas de laravel

Comment: Vale, es que como habías puesto que lo tenías en  /var/www/proyecto/public, pues por aclararlo

Comment: Pon el index.php, si puedes

Comment: @JaviMollá He editado el post y lo he puesto, he eliminado comentarios para evitar innecesarios, y quiero destacar que ya he probado a omitir los "/.." del principio de los ficheros para ver si era por culpa de las rutas pero el resultado viene a ser el mismo, maldito apache.. He conseguido que me escriba en el log de laravel, ya que el archivo .env no lo tenia definido, ahora me guarda en laravel.log algun error, lo pego arriba para que lo mireis. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Dice que no encuentra el comando Composer pero tu dices en algún comentario que sí que lo tienes instalado. ¿Puede ser un problema de permisos del usuario de Apache y la instalación de Composer?

Comment: Como podría comprobar algo de eso? realmente yo he hecho el chown www-data para que pueda leer la carpeta, y si creo un index.php con phpinfo por ejemplo si que puede pintarlo en la web, este en la carpeta que este, pero este error me ha dejado patidifuso, porque lo instale de manera global y tube que hacerlo para instalar el proyecto inicial siguiendo la doc de la pagina web de composer

Comment: Conseguido!, era culpa de composer, he reinstalado desde 0 todo y lo he conseguido hacer funcionar, he ido paso a paso configurando todo y a la perfeccion.

Comment: Yo estuve batallando para lograr hacer deploy de un proyecto Laravel en un VPS, pero seguí los pasos de este [tutorial](https://diarioprogramador.com/aprende-como-realizar-deploy-de-tu-proyecto-en-laravel-en-un-vps-desde-cero-te-lo-ensenamos-de-manera-corta-y-precisa/) y lo logré hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Era culpa de composer, en apache la configuración estaba perfecta.
Para empezar, tenia el archivo .env mal escrito con lo cual no me guardaba los registros de log y no sabia que problema habia:

```
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug !!!!!!!!
```

Gracias a eso consegui descubrir que estaba fallando composer con lo cual intento instalarlo y llegamos al siguiente fallo; necesitaba php 7.2 con lo cual instale las dependencias necesarias:

```
apt-get -y install unzip zip nginx php7.2 php7.2-mysql php7.2-fpm php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xml php7.2-curl
```

Para seguir reinstale todo composer de manera global siguiendo estos comandos:

```
apt update && apt upgrade
apt install php-mcrypt php-gd php-mbstring hhvm phpunit
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Creamos o clonamos un proyecto:

`git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git`

Instalamos composer si es clonado:  `composer install`

Damos permisos: `chown www-data: -R * && chown www-data: -R .*`

Generamos la clave y renombramos el .env:

```
mv .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
```

copiamos la clave en config/app.php

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 
'base64:7fO0S9TxZu8M2NwBWVEQsjPGRi+D1t6Ws8i0Y2yW/vE='),
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

Y ya teniendo claro como usar el virtual host de apache deberia mostrar la pagina,

Comment: Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda, aunque parezca una tonteria, el brainstorm creo que es la mejor forma de darse cuenta de las cosas, ademas de contar los problemas que tienes para darte cuenta de tus propios fallos. Que haria sin esta comunidad <3